# Error in Sonar Runner Execution- "Unable to register extension org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdSensor"

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

Sonar version - 5.1
Sonar runner Version - 2.4

When I am trying to execute sonar runner am getting the below error:

> ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
>   org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
>       at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
>       at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
>       at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
>       at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
>       at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
>       at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
>       at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
>       at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to register extension org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdSensor
>       at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.addExtension(ComponentContainer.java:186)
>       at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ExtensionInstaller.doInstall(ExtensionInstaller.java:78)
>       at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ExtensionInstaller.install(ExtensionInstaller.java:57)
>       at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.addExtensions(ModuleScanContainer.java:244)
>       at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:123)
>       at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:90)
>       at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
>       at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235)
>       at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230)
>       at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:220)
>       at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
>       at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
>       at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:57)
>       at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:45)
>       at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:135)
>       at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
>       at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
>       at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:158)
>       at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
>       at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
>       at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
>       ... 9 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonar/api/batch/AbstractViolationsStaxParser
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
>       at org.picocontainer.injectors.AdaptingInjection$2.run(AdaptingInjection.java:217)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at org.picocontainer.injectors.AdaptingInjection.injectionFieldAnnotated(AdaptingInjection.java:209)
>       at org.picocontainer.injectors.AdaptingInjection.fieldAnnotatedInjectionAdapter(AdaptingInjection.java:188)
>       at org.picocontainer.injectors.AdaptingInjection.createComponentAdapter(AdaptingInjection.java:57)
>       at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehaviorFactory.createComponentAdapter(AbstractBehaviorFactory.java:44)
>       at org.picocontainer.behaviors.OptInCaching.createComponentAdapter(OptInCaching.java:45)
>       at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.addComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:535)
>       at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.access$300(DefaultPicoContainer.java:83)
>       at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer$AsPropertiesPicoContainer.addComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1148)
>       at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.addExtension(ComponentContainer.java:184)
>       ... 34 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonar.api.batch.AbstractViolationsStaxParser
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
>       ... 48 more

Comment: Which version of PMD is installed on your SonarQube instance ?

Comment: This the version : PMD [pmd]-2.4.1-Analyze Java code with PMD 4.2.5.

Comment: I have the same problem - how did you solve it? What was the problem?

Comment: Facing same issue with SonarQube server 4.5.4 and PMD plugin 2.4.1. How can this be resolved ?

Comment: Similar issue that helped me... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030512/jenkins-sonar-check-failure-caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-so

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error after connecting to a new SonarQube server, which was running a newer backend version than the previous server.

Upgrading my SonarLint plugin to the latest resolved the issue. See the [SonarLint page](https://www.sonarlint.org/) for the latest version for your IDE.