# Jenkins sonar check failure: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonar.api.checks.NoSonarFilter

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube

When I call Jenkins build job, It throw following error and job failed.*

Can anyone have saw this error?

Jenkins version: 1.642.1

Sonar version: 5.4 (Java plugin 3.5)

Here is the error info:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1:sonar (default-cli) on project ods-replicator: Unable to register extension org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor: Lorg/sonar/api/checks/NoSonarFilter;: org.sonar.api.checks.NoSonarFilter -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1:sonar (default-cli) on project ods-replicator: Unable to register extension org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor
    ......
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to register extension org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:36)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.RunnerBootstrapper.execute(RunnerBootstrapper.java:81)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:112)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to register extension org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.addExtension(ComponentContainer.java:241)
    ...
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/sonar/api/checks/NoSonarFilter;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AdaptingInjection$2.run(AdaptingInjection.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AdaptingInjection.injectionFieldAnnotated(AdaptingInjection.java:209)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AdaptingInjection.fieldAnnotatedInjectionAdapter(AdaptingInjection.java:188)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AdaptingInjection.createComponentAdapter(AdaptingInjection.java:57)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehaviorFactory.createComponentAdapter(AbstractBehaviorFactory.java:44)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.OptInCaching.createComponentAdapter(OptInCaching.java:45)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.addComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:536)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.access$300(DefaultPicoContainer.java:84)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer$AsPropertiesPicoContainer.addComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1149)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.addExtension(ComponentContainer.java:239)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonar.api.checks.NoSonarFilter
    at org.sonar.classloader.ParentFirstStrategy.loadClass(ParentFirstStrategy.java:39)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:87)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:76)
    ... 77 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: SonarQube 5.4 being shipped with version 3.10 of the Java Plugin, why do you need to use version 3.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The listed compatibility for the version 3.5 of the Java plugin ends at 5.1. There have been API changes in the 5.x series, so this can probably be solved with an upgrade of the Java plugin.

Comment: Thank you very much, I upgrade the Java plugin to 3.11, the problem have fixed.

Comment: You used plugin 3.0.1 "org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1:sonar". Where do you set the java 3.5 version? and how to upgrade it to 3.11? I'm confused but I don't see explicit reference to those versions in your output, or mine...

Comment: @user2800708 3.5 is the version of the SonarQube Java Plugin.

Comment: The question is, where do you set that?

Comment: By installing that version of the plugin in your SonarQube server